# WebMatrix 3 - WebGrid and ADO.NET Dataset with DB2

Tags: db2, webmatrix, webgrid

I'm querying a DB2 server using WebMatrix.   I figured it would be easier for quick, proof of concept related tasks... but using DB2 rather than its built-in providers has been challenge, to say the least.

I know my results are coming back since I can iterate thru my dataset just fine and see my results.

I'm trying to use the built-in WebGrid() function within WebMatrix to display my results and keep getting errors:

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.WebGrid(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, string, int, bool,
>   bool, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' has
>   some invalid arguments

My code is basically:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
DataTable td = new DataTable;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT USER, GROUP FROM DBO.TEST", connString);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

var results = new WebGrid(ds.Tables[0].Rows);
```

Of course, its failing on:

```
var results = new WebGrid(ds.Tables[0].Rows);
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.   I'm assuming I need to convert this to a System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, but no idea how to accomplish this...?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a DataTable into a WebGrid. The WebGrid wants an Enumerable that has public properties that it can use as column names. What you can do is to use [Linq To DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to project the content of the DataTable into a more suitable form. The WebGrid will accept an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
DataTable td = new DataTable;
string query = @"SELECT USER, GROUP FROM DBO.TEST";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
da.Fill(dt);
var data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { 
        User = r.Field<string>("USER"),
        Group = r.Field<string>("GROUP")
    });

WebGrid results = new WebGrid(data);
```